# How to remove <response> element from json web service when using _serialize in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Cakephp _serialize() automatically appends a response element when it is used to generate a json web service. I am using AngularJS and this response element causes problem for the front-end to parse. How can this  element be removed from Cakephp? I am using Cakephp 2.4.5

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: Cakephp does _not_ automatically add a response key to json responses. If that's what you're observing you need to identify what is responsible. Please add some reproducible code, and the output, to the question.

Comment: I use CakePHP and Angular JS successfully  and Cake don't add a thing to my response./ You have to go deeper.